# Can I pass a value to js function from crm field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I have two fields that use the same function (called by `OnChange` event), I wonder if there is an option to pass the field's value to javascript function (for validation) without using XRM.

Write a function with the `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("field").getValue();` - is the only option that I have?

Do I have to write two different functions to two different fields that calls the same function ?

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, you could pass `this` as an argument to the onChange function. The `this` keyword would then refer to the element on witch the change occurred.

Comment: @Olian04 yes that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From CRM form control perspective, you can have a defined library which contains below generic function.

```
function generic_onchange(execContext){
    var myControl = execContext.getEventSource().getName();
    var myControlValue = execContext.getEventSource().getValue();
}
```

When you configure the `onchange` event for your both controls with the above function, select the checkbox "Pass execution context as first parameter".

Update:
When `addOnChange` is being used to attach function to event, execution context is passed by Default as the first Parameter.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_addOnChange)

> The function will be added to the bottom of the event handler pipeline. The execution context is automatically set to be the first parameter passed to the event handler.

Comment: Nice, In my project we are using the addOnChange() and not by CRM ui, what should I use as execContext or it's a regular syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, than this might be what you are looking for:

```js
function eventHandler(obj) {
  alert(obj.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="one" onChange="eventHandler(this)">
<input type="text" placeholder="two" onChange="eventHandler(this)">
```